# jQuery getMonth issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to extract date format in `data tables`. The format I want like `d/M/Y`.I have done using `jquery` but If i use `d/M/Y` format month results are coming wrongly and if I use `M/d/Y` will give correct results.
I want format to be `d/M/Y`. How to resolve this?

Below is my code,

```
{
  orderable: false,
  "mData": null,
  "aaSorting": false,
  "aTargets": [4],
  "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
    var date = full['updated_at'];
    var javascriptDate = new Date(date);
    javascriptDate = javascriptDate.getDate() + 1 + "/" + 
    javascriptDate.getMonth() + "/" + javascriptDate.getFullYear();
    return javascriptDate;
  },
},
```

Comment: Why have you not read [the documentation of getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)? Would that not be the first thing you do when a standard function does not work the way you expect?

Comment: Additionally, why have you not searched for answers regarding getMonth before asking a new question about it? It would even have taken less time than writing a question.I really don't understand this, it makes no sense.

Comment: Thirdly, you seem to want to format a date for display on the screen. Maybe [the `toLocaleString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_Compatibility) is a better choice for this task. Try it before writing your own date format code.

Comment: Even the simplest search for "javascript getmonth" brings up dozens of results that all explain the behavior of that method. It's *completely impossible* that you did not find anything. You have chosen not to read any of them, that's the issue here. (Don't bother writing "yes I have read" until you show me the search terms that do not lead to a usable result and at least five articles that you have read that do not explain the function.)

Comment: Hi ALL,   I have got the solution below is working code, ' var date        = full['updated_at'].replace(/\-/g, '/'); var new_date    = new Date(date);    var year        = new_date.getFullYear(); var month       = new_date.getMonth() + 1;var day         = new_date.getDate(); if (day < 10) { day = "0" + day;}if (month < 10) {month = "0" + month }
                           return  day+'/'+month+'/'+year;'

Comment: @Mohakumar, It is perfectly OK to answer and accept your own question. Perhaps it will help other people in the future.